# Scala apply a function for each row in a dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, flatmap

I have a dataframe in Scala, where I need to apply a function for each row:

```
val df1 // this df is the initial df which has rows in it
val df2 = df1.flatMap( row => postToDB(row))
```

I need to write a function called postToDB where i need to return the failed records to the database and finally return a Dataframe of rows back.

```
def postToDB(val: Row): DataFrame = {

  try{
    //Try inserting to db , this is successful if failed exception is caught.
  } catch {
    case ex: Exception => ex.printStackTrace()
    //return failed rows as a dataframe 
  } 
}
```

How do I apply the function postToDB for each row and return only the failed rows as a dataframe back?

Answer (score 0):

### you can use Optional return type.

```
import spark.implicits._


val df1 // this df is the initial df which has rows in it

val df2 = df1.flatMap( row => postToDB(row))

df2.map(println).getOrElse("successfull")

def postToDB ( val: Row ): Optional[DataFrame] = {
  try {
    //Try inserting to db , this is successful if failed exception is caught.

     None // if success return none
  } catch {
    case ex: Exception => {
     ex.printStackTrace()
     Some(spark.createDF(val)) //return failed rows as a dataframe 
  }
}
```

Comment: this isn't working the Some(spark.createDF(val) is written in my code as sparkSession.createDataFrame(sparkSession.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq),  schema), i need to convert each row  **val** to a list, I am getting exception here

Comment: just debugged sparkSession.sparkContext is null inside the flatMap

Comment: can i ask for the Row class definition.

Comment: sparkcontext is not accessible and cannot be usable inside a map since map is distributed.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the return type of postToDB. You return a dataframe which is an illegal type in this context.

A method provided to flatMap should return a Traversable as the interface for flatMap is:

```
flatMap[U](func: (T) ⇒ TraversableOnce[U])(implicit arg0: Encoder[U]): Dataset[U]
```

Dataframe does not implement TraversableOnce.

Instead simply return a list, either empty or with the single row as follows:

```
def postToDB(row: Row): Traversable[Row] = {

  try{
    //Try inserting to db , this is successful if failed exception is caught.
    List()
  } catch {
    case ex: Exception => ex.printStackTrace()
    List(row)
  } 
}
```

Note: You cannot use Dataframe, Dataset, SparkContext or any of the constructs relating to the distributed elements of spark from within the flatMap method (or any method serialized to the worker including UDF, method to map etc.). Spark allows to send workers only methods which work on standard Scala objects or Spark objects which are not distributed (E.g. Row).